# Code isnt taking the right numbes

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My javascript code is not taking the numbers of the value, he is taking only `1` or `2`, `1` to the smallest number and `2` to the biggest number. I have to do something different to get value numbers?

JSFiddle

```js
var valor1 = document.getElementById('myChart31').value,
  nome1 = document.getElementById('myChart31').name,
  valor2 = document.getElementById('myChart32').value,
  nome2 = document.getElementById('myChart32').name;

Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {
    var width = chart.chart.width,
      height = chart.chart.height,
      ctx = chart.chart.ctx,
      type = chart.config.type;

    if (type == 'doughnut') {
      var percent = Math.round((chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[0] * 100) /
        (chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[0] +
          chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[1]));
      var oldFill = ctx.fillStyle;
      var fontSize = ((height - chart.chartArea.top) / 100).toFixed(2);

      ctx.restore();
      ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle"

      var text = percent + "%",
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = (height + chart.chartArea.top) / 2;

      ctx.fillStyle = chart.config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[0];
      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
      ctx.fillStyle = oldFill;
      ctx.save();
    }
  }
});


var config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        valor1,
        valor2,
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#F7464A",
        "#46BFBD",
      ],
      label: 'Expenditures'
    }],
    labels: [
      nome1 + ": " + valor1,
      nome2 + ": " + valor2,
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Pedro Henrique Kuzminskas Miyazaki de Souza'
    },
    animation: {
      animateScale: true,
      animateRotate: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var total = dataset.data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
            return previousValue + currentValue;
          });
          var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
          var precentage = Math.floor(((currentValue / total) * 100) + 0.5);
          return precentage + "%";
        }
      }
    }
  }
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart3").getContext("2d");
window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config); {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart3">
  <input type="hidden" id="myChart31" name="Pedro" value="50">
  <input type="hidden" id="myChart32" name="Henrique" value="50">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Where do you expect to get different values? You're never using `randomScalingFactor`.

Comment: But in the `1%` should be `50%`, its not showing 50%

Comment: Look at how you're calculating `percent`. You're doing `Math.round(50 / (50 + 50))` -> `Math.round(50 / 100)` -> `Math.round(0.5)` -> `1`.